# Eliminar coleccion en MongoDB queda Null ocupando espacio

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Tengo una coleccion de `objetId` que es un array. En resumen (Array de post) que sería `Posts.post`

Todo funciona de 10. Pero al eliminar un post por ID, lo hace aunque deja un Null junto al ID, y queda ocupando espacio en memoria. Puesto que cuando lo lleve al front lo deberia filtrar !== null y no quiero hacer eso de ser posible, les dejo el código a ver si me equivoco en algo o desconozco alguna forma. Gracias!

Devolución al Eliminar y volver a consultar el usuario:

```js
"phone": 45452254,
  "posts": [
    {
      "post": null,
      "_id": "63af0eeeadb6c7e315c1d88e"
    },
    {
      "post": {
        "_id": "63af0f06adb6c7e315c1d894",
        "status": "2",
        "picture": "22",
        "description": "asdwqd33",
```

Script de eliminado:

```js
router.delete("/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  //queda en null
  const { id } = req.params;
  Post.deleteOne({ _id: id })
    .then(() => res.send("Post Borrado"))
    .catch((error) => next(error));
});
```

Comment: Parece que hay un post hook que en lugar de eliminar pone en null el valor. Puedes confirmar eso?

Comment: Podrías mostrar cómo tienes tus esquemas de Mongoose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final pude solucionarlo, lo que tuve que hacer era un update al modelo shelter pulleando el post que tenia ese id.

```
await Shelter
        .updateOne({ "posts.post": id }, { $pull: { posts: { post: id } } })
        .then(() => res.send("Post eliminado"))
        .catch((error) => next(error));
    });
```

Gracias! Espero le sirva a alguien mas.